# Где я ошиблась?

Tags: c

Почему у меня постоянно показывает ноль?

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    float f, n;
    int r = 0;
    int t = 2;

    printf("Vvedite n=");
    scanf_s("%f", &n);

    if (0 <= t && t <= 2) {
        f = 1.5 + r;
    }
    if (2 < t && t < 5) {
        f = r;
    }
    if (5 <= t && t <= 10) {
        f = 2 * r;
    }
    if (n == 1.5) {
        r = 2.5;
    }
    if (n == 3.4) {
        r = 1.5;
    }
    if (n == 2.6) {
        r = 10.5;
    }
    printf("f raven %d", f);
    getchar();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41718/discussion-on-question-by----).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поздно присваивать `r`, когда `f` уже подсчитан. Поменяй местами блоки.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    float f, n;
    int r = 0;
    int t = 1;

    printf("Vvedite n=");
    scanf_s("%f", &n);

    if (0 <= t && t <= 2) {
        f = 1.5 + r;
    }
    if (2 < t && t < 5) {
        f = r;
    }
    if (5 <= t && t <= 10) {
        f = 2 * r;
    }
    if (n == 1.5) {
        r = 2.5;
    }
    if (n == 3.4) {
        r = 1.5;
    }
    if (n == 2.6) {
        r = 10.5;
    }
    printf("f raven %f", f);
    getchar();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `%f` это `float`, как `%s` это `string`?

Comment: Ну это же не ответ... `n` в вычислениях по-прежнему не используется и я не уверен, отличается ли вообще этот код от кода в вопросе.